# Can SPRING.NET create an XML file, given the object I want to use for IoC?

Tags: xml-serialization, spring.net

I want Spring.NET to generate a matching XML file for the following class :

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
    public string String1 { get; set; } 
    public string String2 { get; set; } 
    public string String3 { get; set; } 
    public string String4 { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I do it? Does spring.NET support any serializing of this sort?

When I think about "spring .net serializing" I mean this output XML :

```
    <property name ="Id" value=""/>
    <property name ="Date" value=""/>
    <property name ="String1" value=""/>
    <property name ="String2" value=""/>
    <property name ="String3" value=""/>
    <property name ="String4" value=""/>
```

i.e. - I need to generate the matching XML to be used as a configuration file for my spring.net based product.

Comment: Do you want to serialize the object, or do you want to configure the object in an spring.net ioc configuration file?

Comment: Serialize - as in automatic way to generate XML for my class.

Comment: What would you like to use the xml for? Have you tried .NET's [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)? That would work pretty well for the simple class in your question.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)XmlSerializer[/link], However Spring.net serializes things a lot differently from microsoft's XML serializer. The problem is that Spring.NET names the properties, and microsoft do not (they assume your property in C# is to be an attribute in XML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring.net does not come with such a tool, afaik. You might want to install the [Spring.NET Visual Studio Add-In](http://springframework.net/vsaddin/index.html), which provides intellisense assistance when writing Spring XML configuration files in VS.NET 2010. It makes your Spring.NET xml life a lot easier.

Comment: What you describe might actually be a nice feature for this add-in: when you enter a type, it automatically fills out the public properties or constructor arguments. You can place a [feature request in their issue tracker](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNETVSADDIN).